# How do I get total webform submission count of multiple webforms?

Tags: views, webforms

I am able to get the webform submission count total for single webforms, but when I filter for multiple webforms (using the OR operator) it only shows the total count for 1 of the webforms. How can I have Views add the counts for all of the webforms I filter?

Comment: What version of the Webform module are you using? Drupal 7 or 8.

Comment: I am using Webform Version: 7.x-4.16. I did figure out a solution - although not using Views. Will answer my own question shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem - albeit not using Views - to accomplish what I wanted to do.

My goal was to have a counter on a page where it showed how many submissions for certain forms have been submitted. I needed to show a combined total of 2 or more webforms but could not accomplish this with Views.

I did find this code that led me to my solution:

First, need to include webform_submissions:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.submissions');
```

Then added this line:

```
webform_get_submission_count($nid, $uid = NULL)
```

I took out the $uid as I did not need to filter by user and made multiple calls for the different webforms I needed:

```
$a = webform_get_submission_count($node->nid = '6');
$b = webform_get_submission_count($node->nid = '7');
```

I then put the following line to add the 2 variables to get me the total that I can then use on my page:

```
$c = $a + $b;
```

This solutions was actually better for me because with Views I could never get the No Results Behavior to show **0** when there were no submissions.